# Given $P \succeq 0$, if $x \neq 0$ and $x^T P x=0$, can we conclude $Px=0$?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

For a positive semidefinite matrix $P$ (i.e., for any $x$, $x^TPx\ge0$, it is denoted as $P \succeq 0$). If $x$ is nonzero and $x^TPx=0$, can we conclude $Px=0$? If so, how to prove it?

I do not understand the solution to exercise 10.1 in Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*, where $P$ is positive semidefinite, and the solution says if for a nonzero $x$, $x^TPx=0$, since $P\succeq0$, we conclude $Px=0$.

Another related question: if $P\succ0$ and $x^TPx=0$, can we conclude $x=0$? If so, how to prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What facts do you know about symmetric and positive semidefinite matrices?

Comment: For the second part, one definition of $P\succ 0$ is that $x^T P x>0$ for all nonzero $x$. So under that definition the desired conclusion is immediate. (There are, however, other definitions of positive definiteness. These are equivalent to the one I just said, but the proof of your condition will no longer be as simple.)

Comment: Can you add the definition of P⪰0?

Comment: Sketch: Since $P$ is positive semi-definite, $P$ is diagonalizable by a suitable orthogonal matrix. So $x$ can be expressed in terms of linear combination of the eigenvectors of $P$ (here let's say $e_1,\cdots,e_n$, where $e_i\ne 0$), like $x=\sum_i x_ie_i$. Then $Q:=x^TPx=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2e_i^Te_i$, where $\lambda_i(\ge 0)$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $P$. $Q=0$ implies $\lambda_i>0\Rightarrow x_i=0$ and hence $Px=0$.

Comment: @Brauer Suzuki added.

Comment: @Katie Imach: if $P$ is decomposed in diagonal form, it is $P=U\Lambda U^T$, can you please give more details how can we get $\sum_i \lambda_ix_i^2e_i^Te_i$ from $x^TPx=x^TU\Lambda U^Tx$?

Comment: You could do it by a straightforward calculation ($x^TU^T\Lambda Ux=\sum_{i,j,k}\lambda_jx_ix_ku_{ji}u_{jk}$ and use orthonormality $\sum_ku_{ik}u_{jk}=\delta_{ij}$ to simplify further), but a bit tedious. Think about it in a more abstract manner: orthonormal eigenvectors $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ (s.t. $Pe_i=\lambda_ie_i$) are guaranteed to exist and form a basis. So you can in principle expand $x$ on that basis $x=\sum_ix_ie_i$. Then it follows from linearity that $Px=\sum_i\lambda_ix_ie_i$ and hence $x^TPx=\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j\lambda_ie_j^Te_i$. Observe $e_i^Te_j=\delta_{ij}$ to find the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the spectral theorem as indicated by Katie in the comments, there exists a square matrix $Q$ such that $P=Q^TQ$ (take the square roots of the (non-negative) eigenvalues). Now $|Qx|^2=x^TPx=0\Rightarrow Qx=0\Rightarrow Px=0$. Your second question follows directly from the definition as commented by Semiclassical.